# create a slot in qt to react to a click of a pushbutton

Tags: qt, tabwidget, qpushbutton

I have a start/stop button which i want to control which tab is being shown in the tabWidget.

here's how I'm doing it.

```
// Control START/STOP actions
void gui::start_stop()
{
    if (acquisition == 0)
    {
        acquisition = 1;
        ui->pushButton->setText("STOP \nACQUISITION");
        ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: #8090d0; border-radius: 5px; color : #ffffff;");
        ui->tab_acquisition->raise();

    }

    else
    {
        acquisition = 0;
        ui->pushButton->setText("START \nACQUISITION");
        ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: #6673a6; border-radius: 5px; color : #ffffff;");
        ui->tab_settings->raise();

    }
}
```

the problem is that the tab_acquisition and tab_settings don't get raised

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to tell us if you have issues with this method, if you try to connect it to the clicked signal make sure it's declared with *slots* access specifier.

Comment: sorry, the problem is that the tab_acquisition and tab_settings don't get raised

Comment: Have you tried calling [setCurrentWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtabwidget.html#setCurrentWidget) with the pointer to a widget that is added to your tabWidget? LE: instead of calling _raise()_

Comment: tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->tab_acquisition); is not working? Is tabWidget a [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtabwidget.html), or what type? If it's QTabWidget are those two widgets added as tabs into tabWidget?

Comment: Zlatomir's suggestion of QTabWidget::setCurrentWidget should have the desired functionality. I use it all the time.

Comment: just a small correction, the code most likely should be preceded by _ui->_ so: _ui->tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->tab_acquisition);_